# .NetCore Database ILoggerProvider repository context null

Tags: logging, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to build a custom LoggerProvider that writes all logs to the database via a repository/dbcontext.  I added logging in the ConfigureServices and Added the new provider in the Configure as follows

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //Register EntityFramework Core Datacontext for Dependency Injection
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            //Register Repositories for Dependency Injection
            services.AddScoped<ILogRepository, LogRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ICountryRepository, CountryRepository>();

            services.AddLogging();      

            //Add CORS
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Open", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                    builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });

            services.AddControllers()
                    .AddMvcOptions(o =>
                    {
                        //Allow XML as a request Accept type
                        o.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
                    });

            
            
        }
```

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory log, ILogRepository logRepo)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            //Add Database Logging Provider
            log.AddProvider(new LoggerDatabaseProvider(logRepo));

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();      

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseCors("Open");

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

I created a standard LogRepository which uses the datacontext that was registered in the ConfigureServices

```
public class LogRepository : ILogRepository, IDisposable
    {
        private DataContext _dataContext;

        public LogRepository(DataContext dataContext)
        {
            _dataContext = dataContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataContext));
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Log>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            return await _dataContext.Logs.ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<Log> GetByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            return await _dataContext.Logs.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == id);
        }

        public async Task<Log> CreateAsync(Log log)
        {
            var addedEntity = _dataContext.Logs.Add(log);
            await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return addedEntity.Entity;
        }

        public async Task UpdateAsync(int id, Log log)
        {
            if (!await ExistsAsync(id))
                return;

            _dataContext.Entry(log).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public async Task DeleteAsync(int id)
        {
            var foundEntity = await GetByIdAsync(id);
            if (foundEntity == null)
                return;

            _dataContext.Logs.Remove(foundEntity);
            await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public async Task<bool> ExistsAsync(int id)
        {
            return await _dataContext.Logs.AnyAsync(c => c.Id == id);
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if(disposing)
            {
                if(_dataContext != null)
                {
                    _dataContext.Dispose();
                    _dataContext = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the implementation of the ILogger

```
public class LoggerDatabaseProvider : ILoggerProvider
    {
        private ILogRepository _repo;

        public LoggerDatabaseProvider(ILogRepository repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }

        public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
        {
            return new Logger(categoryName, _repo);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public class Logger : ILogger
        {
            private readonly string _categoryName;
            private readonly ILogRepository _repo;

            public Logger(string categoryName, ILogRepository repo)
            {
                _repo = repo;
                _categoryName = categoryName;
            }

            public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
            {
                return true;
            }

            public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
            {
                    RecordMsg(logLevel, eventId, state, exception, formatter);
            }

            private void RecordMsg<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
            {
                _repo.CreateAsync(new Log
                {
                    LogLevel = logLevel.ToString(),
                    CategoryName = _categoryName,
                    Message = formatter(state, exception),
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
                });
            }

            public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
            {
                return new NoopDisposable();
            }

            private class NoopDisposable : IDisposable
            {
                public void Dispose()
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Im calling the logger from my APIController which is as follows

```
private readonly ICountryRepository _repository;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public CountriesController(ICountryRepository countryRepository, ILogger logger)
        {
            _repository = countryRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(countryRepository));
            _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        }

        // GET: api/Country
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(_repository)}: GetAll");
            var countries = await _repository.GetAllAsync();
            return Ok(countries);
        }
```

I put a breakpoint on my LogRepository and when I hit that breakpoint I see that there is a DataContext.  However, when the LogInformation is called and I look at the Repository, the DataContext is NULL.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

According to your codes, I found you have set the Dispose method in LogRepository class to dispose the dbcontext.

This is the reason why the dbcontext is null when you call the LogRepository method.

I suggest you could remove the `_dataContext.Dispose` method to let the DI to manage the LogRepository and dbcontext and then it will work well.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
public class LogRepository : ILogRepository, IDisposable
{
    private TestDbcontext _dataContext;

    public LogRepository(TestDbcontext dataContext)
    {
        _dataContext = dataContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataContext));
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Log>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await _dataContext.Logs.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<Log> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _dataContext.Logs.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == id);
    }

    public async Task<Log> CreateAsync(Log log)
    {
        var addedEntity = _dataContext.Logs.Add(log);
        await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return addedEntity.Entity;
    }

    public async Task UpdateAsync(int id, Log log)
    {
        if (!await ExistsAsync(id))
            return;

        _dataContext.Entry(log).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task DeleteAsync(int id)
    {
        var foundEntity = await GetByIdAsync(id);
        if (foundEntity == null)
            return;

        _dataContext.Logs.Remove(foundEntity);
        await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task<bool> ExistsAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _dataContext.Logs.AnyAsync(c => c.Id == id);
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        //if (disposing)
        //{
        //    if (_dataContext != null)
        //    {
        //        _dataContext.Dispose();
        //        _dataContext = null;
        //    }
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Brando i commented out the code as suggested.  I no longer get a _dataContext null exception, however i do get an {"Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.\r\nObject name: 'DataContext'."}

Comment: I even removed the entire IDisposable interface from the LogRepository and same error

Comment: Could you please tell me which line throw this error? This codes is working well on my side.

Comment: Its the data context.add

Comment: I suggest you could try to set the Logging LogLevel to trace to see when the dbcontext is disposed. It seems you have disposed the dbcontext in other middleware.